# Is there a difference in a spartan and elite in Halo 3 MP?

Tags: halo-3

The title pretty much says it all. Is there a difference (mainly thinking in respect to the hitbox) for the elite and spartan in Halo 3 multiplayer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the hitboxes are the same for both.  However, the neck of the elite is rumoured to be immune to damage except from a charged plasma pistol shot.

> In Halo 3, the neck of an Elite (regardless what Armor Permutation used) is completely immune to any form of damage except for a shot from a charged Plasma Pistol. In addition, the projectile will simply pass through the neck, as though the neck wasn't there, without a blood spatter. This is because both Elites and Spartans share the same hitbox (where you can hit the character), but have different models.

Source: [Halo Wikia](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Armor_Permutations)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a bit late to answer this, but here it is. Every hitbox is exactly the same. Wether you have bulky armor, slim armor, or if you play as an elite.
I will tell you this though, if you play as an elite it will make you more noticeable in the crowd. That's why I play as them, because it's more of a challenge.
But it wouldn't matter if the hitboxes were different, wether you play as a Spartan
or an Elite is entirely up to you. And don't listen to people who say people who play as Spartans are better, or vice versa. Skill depends entirely on the person and how long they have been playing. Hope this helped!